# I couldn't setup ssl to my localhost using node js

Tags: node.js, express, http, https, openssl

I installed OpenSSL, I created cert.pem and key.pem, but I couldn't run the server using node js and express js, I think there is an error in my keys, how can I solve this error, thanks in advance

Error
[image]

dirname :

[image]

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('https')
const {v4 : uuidv4} = require('uuid')
const fs = require('fs');

app.set('view engine','ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

const options = {
   key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
   cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
   res.redirect(`/${uuidv4()}`)

 })
 app.get('/:room' , (req,res) =>{
    res.render('meet' , {roomId : req.params.room})
 })

 server.createServer(options, (req,res) =>{
    console.log('worked')
 }).listen(3030, "192.168.1.20")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is because the SSL certificate is old so I found a package and it worked

https://dev.to/tingwei628/using-mkcert-in-node-js-ijm